# Normed vector space, closed convex set $C$, compact convex set $D$. Show $C+D$ is closed and convex.

Tags: functional-analysis

**EDIT:** Turns out $D$ is also convex. I misread the problem! My proof is now more or less complete, but I would like feedback.

**The problem is:**

*Let $\mathbb{E}$ be a normed vector space. Show that if $C \subset \mathbb{E}$ is convex and closed and $D \subset \mathbb{E}$ is compact, then $C + D$ is a closed convex set.*

**What I have so far:**

A set $C$ is closed if it contains all its limit points (as defined in part a). A set
$D$ in a normed vector space $\mathbb{E}$ is compact if it is *sequentially compact*--every
sequence $\{d_n\} \in D$ has a
subsequence that converges in $D$.

Take $x$, $y \in C + D$ where $x = c_x + d_x$, $y=c_y + d_y$. Then we have for all $t \in [0,1]$
\begin{align*}
    tx + (1-t)y &= t(c_x + d_x) + (1-t)(c_y + d_y)\\
    &= tc_x + (1-t)c_y + td_x + (1-t)d_y\\
    &= c + d \text{ where } c \in C\text{, }d\in D \text{ since } C\text{, }D \text{ are convex.}
\end{align*}

Therefore $C + D$ is convex. Now we must show $C + D$ is closed. Let $x$ be a limit point of $C+D$, then we can define a sequence $x_n \in C+D$, $x_n \rightarrow x$. We can write $x_n = c + d_n$ for $c \in C$ and $d_n \in D$. Since $D$ is compact we can take a convergence subsequence $d_{k_n} \rightarrow d \in D$ of $\{d_n\}$ and instead define $x_n = c + d_{k_n}$. Thus $x_n \rightarrow c + d \in C + D$. Thus $C+D$ is closed.

Comment: This is obviously false; for example if $C=\{0\}$ then $C+D=D$.

Comment: Oh my god. You saying that made me re-examine the fill problem. $D$ is also convex, I just didn't see it since it was in the very top of the problem statement and this is a later subproblem. Editing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of the convexity is correct. As for closedness, it is not clear what you did. Here is how to do it: take a convergent sequence $(x_n) = (c_n + d_n) \subset C+ D$ and put $x = \lim x_n$. Since $D$ is compact, $(d_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(d_{n_k})$ converging to some $d \in D$. Hence, the subsequence $(c_{n_k})$ of $(c_n)$ converges to $x - d:=c$ because $c_{n_k} = x_{n_k} - d_{n_k}$. As $C$ is closed, $c \in C$. Thus, $x = c + d \in C+D$. This shows that $C+D$ is closed.